# Generating all possible strategies for iterated prisoner's dilemma in python

Tags: python, algorithm, simulation, game-theory

The game will / can be played multiple times, i.e. the depth of the game is a fixed number `n>0`. What I want to do is, given that the depth of the game is fixed at `n`, generate all possible unique and consistent strategies for this game.

### Game Overview

The game is played between two strategies `X` and `Y`. Each turn `X` and `Y` will have a history of all previous moves played, but they have have no information about what move the other side is going to play until they have played their own move. The move they can pick are either `+1` or `-1`, and the result of what would happen if they pick either of these moves does not really matter for this question.

### What do I mean by "unique and consistent strategies?"

An example of two "different" strategies that are actually the same is this: 1st strategy is to pick `-1` 10 times in a row and then on the 11th turn and onwards it would only pick `+1`, and the 2nd strategy is to pick `-1` 9 times in a row and then `+1` onwards, but let's say the depth of the game is only `n=8`, so in this case both strategies would produce the same answer against any other strategies. Thus a strategy `X` is different from a strategy `Y` if there exist a strategy `M` where `X` and `Y` deviates at some point in their answer against the strategy `M` within the predefined depth of the game `n`. By consistent I mean that given the history of the game, the answer from the strategy should always be the same (random is not allowed).

### My question

My main question is, if I want a setup where I can simulate all different strategies, what would be a good way to formulate these "strategies" in python? Say we are playing this game at depth 5, which would produce 1024 unique games. What would be a good way to define a strategy or think about a strategy in such a way that I can feed a strategy `X` two lists `[1, 1]`, `[1, -1]`, where the first list are the two moves `X` have played, and the second list contains the two moves the other strategy `Y` have played, and then `X` would have to pick a move based on this information. Like, let's say the strategy for `X` is to play `+1` only if `Y` haven't played `-1` the last two turns, and the strategy for `Y` is to just alternate between `+1` and `-1`. What is a good way to represent those two strategies in such a way that I can easily evaluate them, but most importantly, What is a good interpretation of a strategy in code such that I generate all possible strategies that are unique and consistent?

Note: I am not interested in generating all possible games, what I am interested in is generating all possible strategies.

### Example of different strategies

Examples of strategies based on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mScpHTIi-kM) by Veritasium, which was my main motivation for asking this question. A strategy called Tit for Tat is to copy your opponent's previous move, where your first move is to always play `+1`. Another strategy is to play `+1` and then on the fifth move always play `-1` regardless of your opponent. Another strategy similar to Tit for Tat is to only play `-1` if your opponent has played `-1` two times in a row. The question is what is a good way to formulate these strategies in code such that all possible unique and consistent strategies can be generated.

Comment: I think this is usually referred to as "iterated prisoners' dilemma"

Comment: "not interested in generating all possible games" An $n$ iteration prisoners' dilemma is just a pair of length $n$ binary digits, one for each player.  A "strategy" would be some subset of those pairs.  What you want with "all strategies", then, naively, is the power set of the set of pairs of length $n$ binary digits.  The size of this set is $2^{2^{2n}}$, fyi.

Comment: how does this end ? your setup is not clear. If X and Y are two players... what is the winning condition ?

Comment: @Him Thanks I changed the title to iterated prisoner's dilemma. Your calculation for this sounds a bit strange. Let's say n=2, then $2^{2^{2*2}} = 65536$, but the list of all possible games are this: `((1, 1), (1, 1))`, `((1, 1), (1, -1))`, `((1, 1), (-1, -1))`, `((1, -1), (1, 1))`, `((1, -1), (1, -1))`, `((1, -1), (-1, -1))`, `((-1, -1), (1, 1))`, `((-1, -1), (1, -1))`, `((-1, -1), (-1, -1))` which is 9 unique games, so a bunch of those 65536 strategies would end up producing the same answer anyway and thus they wouldn't be unique strategies.

Comment: @vin I deliberately chose not to define what would happen when picking either choice, or how the game would be scored after `n` turns, since picking a strategy based on that is not really my goal. My goal is mainly just figuring out an interpretation for a strategy such that I can generate all possible strategies. The only information that is available when determining a strategy is the history of my own moves and the history of my opponent's move.

Comment: ohh! then the way I see it.. your problem is a binary tree and the root is simply 4 nodes... after which is your future depth

Comment: also to answer this `such that I can simulate which strategy performs the best during certain confined setups.`  you need to define what you mean by `performs best`

Comment: @vin Ah sorry, I should have left that part out of this post. Answering what `performs best` is not part the of the question of this post. The question in this post is only about generating all possible unique and consistent strategies and nothing more. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

OP wants a way to formulate all possible strategies. In the setup suggested a strategy is selecting one of the two options `[1, -1]`
This makes the setup a binary tree, with X and Y alternating between each other. As the winning situation is not defined the only stop parameter is the tree depth. All strategies here are guaranteed to be different as a binary tree would have only one path to root via parents.

Following examples takes from the small set OP suggested above

```
leaves = []


class Node:
    def __init__(self, parent, depth, data, root_data):
        self.value = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.parent = parent
        if len(root_data) > 0:
            new_data = root_data[0]
            if new_data == -1:
                self.left = Node(self, depth - 1, new_data, root_data[1:])
            elif new_data == 1:
                self.right = Node(self, depth - 1, new_data, root_data[1:])
        else:
            if depth == 0:
                leaves.append(self)
                return
            else:
                self.left = Node(self, depth - 1, -1, [])
                self.right = Node(self, depth - 1, 1, [])


def print_tree(node, level=0, prefix="Root: ", connector="    "):
    if node is not None:
        print(" " * (level * 4) + prefix + str(node.value))
        if node.right is not None:
            print_tree(node.right, level + 1, "├──R: ", "│   ")
        if node.left is not None:
            print_tree(node.left, level + 1, "└──L: ", "    ")


def traverse_to_parent(node):
    path = []
    while node is not None:
        path.append(node.value)
        node = node.parent
    path.reverse()
    return path


if __name__ == '__main__':
    max_depth = 6
    X = [1, 1]
    Y = [1, -1]
    till_now = [e for d in zip(X, Y) for e in d]
    previous_depth = len(X) + len(Y)
    tree = Node(None, max_depth-1, till_now[0], till_now[1:])
    print_tree(tree)
    print("Strategies::")
    for leaf in leaves:
        path = traverse_to_parent(leaf)
        print(f"X:: {path[::2]}  -----   Y:: {path[1::2]}")
```

Output

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.9 nodes.py 
Root: 1
    ├──R: 1
        ├──R: 1
            └──L: -1
                ├──R: 1
                    ├──R: 1
                    └──L: -1
                └──L: -1
                    ├──R: 1
                    └──L: -1
Strategies::
X:: [1, 1, -1]  -----   Y:: [1, -1, -1]
X:: [1, 1, -1]  -----   Y:: [1, -1, 1]
X:: [1, 1, 1]  -----   Y:: [1, -1, -1]
X:: [1, 1, 1]  -----   Y:: [1, -1, 1]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Please show the output and explain what it means.

Comment: I still don't get it. Looks like you're not describing strategies but only games. And "X and Y alternating" sounds wrong, since they make their moves at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am a bit confused as to how to humanly understand these strategies that are printed by the script. For example the first strategy that is printed in your output is `X:: [1, 1, -1]  -----   Y:: [1, -1, -1]`, does that mean `X` will always play `[1, 1, -1]` regardless of what `Y` have played?

Comment: no... it means 
X:: [1, 1, -1]  -----   Y:: [1, -1, -1] 
is one `game`

Comment: Is the strategy the tree that is in the output? It's a bit unclear to me what the strategy is for `X` and `Y`, or how the strategies are to be interpreted in this case

Comment: ohhk.. whatever be the strategy.. it would be limited by the depth. 
A move has only two choices +1 -1

Comment: `strategy` the way I have understood it is a series of sequences X can play

Comment: @vin I can give some examples of strategies based on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mScpHTIi-kM) which was my main motivation for asking this question. A strategy called Tit for Tat is to copy your opponent's previous move, where your first move is always to play `+1`. Another strategy is to play `+1` and then always on the fifth move you play `-1`. Another strategy similar to Tit for Tat is to only play `-1` if your opponent has played `-1` two times in a row.